# How to install OpenJDK 11 on Windows?

Tags: windows, java-11

In the past, Oracle used to publish an executable installers for Windows that would:

- Unpack files
- Add registry keys indicating the installed version and path
- Add the JRE to the system PATH
- Register an uninstaller with Windows.

As of Java 11, the Oracle's free version of Java ([Oracle OpenJDK](http://jdk.java.net/11)) doesn't seem to include an installer. It is just a zip file containing the binaries.

How are we supposed to install OpenJDK 11 on Windows seeing as the aforementioned integrations are no longer there? Aren't they necessary?

Comment: Changing the registry was never actually needed. And when not manipulating the system, you don’t need an uninstaller either.

Comment: [Difference between installing an JDK and using the dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8193008)

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov The answers are outdated and no longer relevant of JDK 11.

Comment: For the future it would be good having an installer/updater. May be we should start an open source project or is there an already existing project?

Comment: @Robert What's exactly outdated in those answers? Output directory layout has changed a bit, but nothing else. Question covers the difference between installation and pure "copying" of JDK. It seems totally relevant.

Comment: @Holger How are native launchers (e.g. IDE) supposed to locate the JDK without a registry key or default install location? The only option that is left is to bundle a JDK with each native application. Is the concept of a global JDK dead?

Comment: @Gili using JAVA_HOME environment variable or through direct path in config like IntelliJ IDEa does it?

Comment: There is a community project [ojdkbuild](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild) which provides Windows installers for OpenJDK. JDK 11 is not available there yet but I hope we will get it soon.

Comment: @Gili http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JVM note how registry does not appear anywhere…

Comment: @Robert well, without a browser plugin, control panel, automatic update tool, nor the ask toolbar crapware, there is not so much left to install.

Comment: Just download the .msi from https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases

Comment: @jfleach ojdkbuild is a totally different thing, from totally different people.

Comment: Jedit and Netbeans use the registry.

Comment: And Eclipse....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenJDK availability for Windows OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991508/openjdk-availability-for-windows-os)

Comment: @BernhardStadler No. This question deals exclusively with the installation of OpenJDK, not the availability.

Comment: @Gili The answers to the question of availabilty for Windows of course also include the availability of installers for Windows. You just need to scroll down a bit.

Answer (score 585, accepted):

1. Extract the zip file into a folder, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\` and it will create a `jdk-11` folder (where the bin folder is a direct sub-folder). You may need Administrator privileges to extract the zip file to this location.
2. Set a PATH:

   - Select Control Panel and then System.
   - Click Advanced and then Environment Variables.
   - Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation to the PATH variable in System Variables.
   - The following is a typical value for the PATH variable: `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11\bin"`
3. Set JAVA_HOME:

   - Under System Variables, click New.
   - Enter the variable name as JAVA_HOME.
   - Enter the variable value as the installation path of the JDK (without the `bin` sub-folder).
   - Click OK.
   - Click Apply Changes.
4. Configure the JDK in your IDE (e.g. IntelliJ or Eclipse).

You are set.

To see if it worked, open up the Command Prompt and type `java -version` and see if it prints your newly installed JDK.

If you want to uninstall - just undo the above steps.

**Note:** You can also point `JAVA_HOME` to the folder of your JDK installations and then set the `PATH` variable to `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`. So when you want to change the JDK you change only the `JAVA_HOME` variable and leave `PATH` as it is.

Comment: Don't forget the registry entries, which are e.g. used by Launch4j for finding installed jre/jdk.

Comment: How would you do if you were using ubuntu

Comment: @Robert - sorry, but this is a specific tool worth its own discussion.

Comment: @WilFerraciolli I added a tag to the question to clarify that it is Windows-specific. I recommend opening a separate question for Ubuntu.

Comment: @Lior: This is just one program I know that uses the registry entries. There may be dozens or hundred of other programs using these registry entries, too.

Comment: It may be so, but: a. I worked with Java since ver 1.1 without setting the registry - so it is not a must. b: the windows registry is commonly considered as a mechanism to avoid (e.g. https://blog.codinghorror.com/was-the-windows-registry-a-good-idea/) - hence I don't think it should be used, if not specifically needed. e.g. - a mistake setting a value in it can lead to a hard-to-recover-from error.

Comment: I have installed OpenJDK on Windows 10 and set JAVA_HOME and PATH. On the Windows command line, I can do "javac -version" and "jshell", but not "java -version". That's strange. IntelliJ works,so I think I'm OK.

Comment: > *You can point the JAVA_HOME to the folder where you have multiple JDK 
installations*.  

This is completely wrong. Many programs and scripts  assume JAVA_HOME points to default java installation (jdk or jre) and they search for binaries under "%JAVA_HOME%\bin". So you CANNOT point JAVA_HOME to folder with *multiple* jdk installations.
   Instead you can add to Path the value "%JAVA_HOME%\bin;" and then (when new JDK installed) you can update JAVA_HOME only

Comment: @Robert what are these registry entries launch4j is looking for?

Comment: @sarkasronie See launch4j source code: https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/git/ci/Release_launch4j-3_12/tree/head_src/head.c#l630 (under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)

Comment: As @craftwar mentioned in the downvoted answer below one may experience the following error when running java --version after following the instructions from the above answer:

Error: opening registry key 'Software\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment'
Error: could not find java.dll
Error: Could not find Java SE Runtime Environment.

This is due to Oracle JDK uninstaller not removing the files in "C:\ProgramData\Oracle", once I removed the "Oracle" directory everything started working as expected.

Comment: Please add that you have to move your Java11 PATH entry to the beginning of the PATH. This to override some (multiple!) path settings to "...\Oracle\Java\javapath". If you don't do this, the test can fail.

Comment: Would be nice if these steps were included in the Installation Instructions on the official OpenJDK website... all it says there is "download and unzip it". I don't understand why they don't mention anything about adding to PATH and setting JAVA_HOME...

Comment: @RoelandVanHeddegem wow, great tip, thanks for saving me time lol

Comment: This is the correct answer. I guess this is a lot more obvious to those of us accustomed to adding values to $PATH on real operating system.

Comment: Can I add the path for Java 8 as well with Java 11 path ?

Comment: wondering why this was not working for me. Issue: my cmd was running on a C from one hdd and I was placing jdk on D: that was on another hdd

Answer (score 280):

### Eclipse Adoptium

For Java 17 and up, you can use the [Eclipse Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/) website. [According to their about section,](https://adoptium.net/about) the Eclipse Adoptium project is the continuation of the original AdoptOpenJDK mission. It currently hosts Java 8, 11 and 16 through 22, offering various installation methods, including .msi installers, which will perform all the things listed in the question (Unpacking, registry keys, PATH variable updating (and JAVA_HOME), uninstaller...).

Earlier, Java 11 was hosted via [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/). It now redirects to Eclipse Adoptium.

Comment: Although the accepted answer is correct, this is a much more convenient way to install any version of the JDK/JRE

Comment: @AJDhaliwal I have edited the answer to more prominently display Eclipse Adoptium.

Comment: adoptopenjdk.net now redirects to Eclipse Adoptium, which doesn't appear to supply old OpenJDK binaries.

Answer (score 41):

Use the [Chocolatey packet manager](https://chocolatey.org/). It's a command-line tool similar to npm. Once you have installed it, use

```
choco install openjdk --version=11.0
```

in an elevated command prompt to install OpenJDK 11 (leave out the `--version` parameter to install the latest version).

To update an installed version to the latest version, type

```
choco upgrade openjdk
```

Pretty simple to use and especially helpful to upgrade to the latest version. No manual fiddling with path environment variables.

Comment: Note that this would install latest version: openjdk-12.0.2_windows-x64

Comment: in case you have other java versions installed you might want to check the path variables and remove/modify the old.

Comment: @Vadzim

 choco install openjdk11

as of today without mentioning the version, it installs openjdk-13

and just to note, it will use the AdoptOpenJDK as in other answers

Comment: As a note for this method, jdk11 is no longer supported and kept up to date. Be sure to use "openjdk11" not "jdk11".   
Per the maintainer: "Sorry for all.
As Oracle requires us to login OTN to install JDK 11, I can't support chocolaty JDK 11 package anymore. Sorry.
I requested remove this JDK 11 package. Please use open jdk package."

Comment: I installed it and when i try `java -version` I get 'java: The term 'java' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.' Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: @GodstimeOsarobo You may need to close & reopen your shell window (cmd/powershell), as only then the PATH environment variable is updated appropriately.

Comment: You can use [chocolatey](https://community.chocolatey.org) and specifically ask for OpenJDKv11: `choco install openjdk --version=11.0`. As noted [here](https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/openjdk/11.0).

Comment: Chocolatey install script for elevated PowerShell (all 1 line):    Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; `
  iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

Comment: this will no longer work. ` The remote file either doesn't exist, is unauthorized, or is forbidden for url 'https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/28/GPL/openjdk-11+28_windows-x64_bin.zip'`

Comment: @1mike12 It seems as the old versions are deprecated. Newer versions like 18 or 19 should work.

Comment: `choco install openjdk --version=11.0` no longer works, I encountered error logs [here](https://gist.github.com/daparic/653c8511e4d7bd760a639e18f31e8e14). I instead used `choco install openjdk` to deal with it.

Answer (score 24):

From the comment by @ZhekaKozlov: [ojdkbuild](https://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild/releases) has OpenJDK builds (currently 8 and 11) for Windows (`zip` and `msi`).

Comment: For me those builds didn't set the PATH variables properly. At lease I can't issue `java -version` and get the desired output.

Comment: I can't find OpenJDK msi. I'll do script and share it in an answer later today that extracts and sets PATH and JAVA_HOME for the machine.

Comment: @vezenkov: Update the answer here (it's community wiki for a reason) and/or open an issue with the project, please.

Comment: To add to the accepted answer if you were upgrading from a previous version I had to even restart the server to see the openjdk version get updated on the command line.

Answer (score 5):

### JDK builds

Basically, there is only one set of source code for the JDK. It is hosted in Mercurial at [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/).
**Anyone can take the source code, produce a build, and post it. So, Oracle created a certification process that should be used to ensure the build is valid. This certification is run by the Java Community Process, which provides a Technology Compatibility Kit (TCK or JCK as Java).** If an organization produces an OpenJDK build that passes the TCK then that build can be described as “Java SE compatible”.

**Eclipse Temurin**
[AdoptOpenJDK](https://blog.adoptopenjdk.net/2021/08/goodbye-adoptopenjdk-hello-adoptium/) has been moved to the [Eclipse Foundation](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/adoptium) and rebranded to **[Eclipse Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/en-GB/)** project. The Adoptium OpenJDK builds are called [Eclipse Temurin](https://adoptium.net/en-GB/temurin/releases/) to distinguish the project from the builds. Eclipse Temurin builds are high-quality, **vendor-neutral**, and TCK-tested under a permissive license. Temurin is available for a wide range of platforms and Java SE versions.

**Zulu**
You can check [Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community/?architecture=x86-64-bit&package=jdk#) from [Azul](https://www.azul.com/). Azul provides open source OpenJDK builds called Azul Zulu for many operating systems and architectures. Azul Platform Core provides 100% open source, fully tested and certified, Java SE standards-compliant, well-curated builds of OpenJDK. Zulu is compliant with Java SE specifications, and has an identical level of performance to the Oracle offering, making it an easy “drop-in” replacement for Oracle HotSpot.

**Amazon Corretto**
You can also use [Amazon Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/corretto/). It is free to use multiplatform, production-ready distribution of the OpenJDK. It comes with long-term support that will include performance enhancements and security fixes. Check the installation instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/windows-7-install.html).

**TCK Compliant**
One more thing I like to highlight here is that all the mentions builds are TCK Compliant. You can see the OpenJDK builds comparison [here](https://devexperts.com/blog/oracle-jdk-vs-openjdk-builds-comparison/) and [here](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/jdk-comparison-matrix/).

Check [this](https://whichjdk.com/) guide to decide which jdk suits best for your needs.

Answer (score 4):

For Java 12 onwards, official General-Availability (GA) and Early-Access (EA) Windows 64-bit builds of the OpenJDK (GPL2 + Classpath Exception) from Oracle are available as tar.gz/zip from the [JDK website](https://jdk.java.net).

If you prefer an installer, there are several distributions. There is a [public Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nFGazvrCvHMZJgFstlbzoHjpAVwv5DEdnaBr_5pKuHo/edit?usp=sharing) and [Blog post](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-3-0-0-ocrt-2021-bca75c88d23b) by the Java Champions community which lists the best-supported OpenJDK distributions. Currently, these are:

- [AdoptOpenJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/) has been superseded by Adoptium/Temurin (Hotspot) and IBM Semeru (OpenJ9)
- [Adoptium Temurin](https://adoptium.net)
- [Amazon Corretto](https://aws.amazon.com/de/corretto)
- [IBM Semeru](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/java/semeru-runtimes/) (with OpenJ9 JVM)
- Liberica from [Bellsoft](https://bell-sw.com)
- [Microsoft Build of OpenJDK](https://www.microsoft.com/openjdk)
- [OpenLogic OpenJDK](https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads)
- [Red Hat OpenJDK](https://developers.redhat.com/products/openjdk)
- [SAPMachine](https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases) (backed by SAP)
- [Zulu Community](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu-community) (backed by Azul Systems)

Answer (score 3):

Scoop installs programs you know and love, from the command line with a minimal amount of friction.

- Install [scoop](https://scoop.sh/)
- Add java `scoop bucket add java`
- Install OpenJDK `scoop.cmd install openjdk17`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answers, it is worth noting that you have to move your JDK Path entry to the top of the Path

[image: Inside System Variables Edit Path and Move Up the latest JDK entry to the top]

Answer (score 1):

https://www.openlogic.com/openjdk-downloads allowed me to pick a 32-bit version of OpenJDK8 (don't ask - Arduino IDE doesn't compile with 11), I think they just wrap around AdoptOpenJDK MSIs but I couldn't find 32-bit distros on AdoptOpenJDK.

Answer (score 1):

WinGet is now available on Windows 10+ to install the Microsoft Build of OpenJDK on your machine. See details and access the downloads page at https://aka.ms/msopenjdk/ where you can find more instructions and packages you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete answer. first of all you have to install the [Chocolatey](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/). to install  Chocolatey run powershell as administrator and run the following command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://community.chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

after this run  open cmd as administrator and run this command

`choco install -y  openjdk11`

it will install the openjdk to the following location

`C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot`

finllay set your **JAVA_HOME** TO

`C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot`

and cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this also.
choco install -y  microsoft-openjdk11