# JDK not detected

Tags: java, java-home

Good day.

I have tried to get my pc to detect my JDK, I want to install the SDK manager, for eclipse, my goal is to run a virtual android device. I have installed the JDK, and set the JAVA_HOME path. Here are some snippets of the path. I am currently running Windows 10 64bit and not finding any links to what else to do. I have been searching for some time now.

[This is the PATH set in System Enviroment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT2bK.png)

[This is the Java installation directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfLNN.png)

When I type echo %JAVA_HOME% the installation directory pops up in the command prompt, but when i type javac - version, i get an error.

[CMD error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oiGAy.png)

Please if anyone know what I am doing wrong please let me know.

Comment: There shouldn't be the need to set the Java home , it is taken care by the installer. Please un install , remove the manul settings and reinstall as local admin and things should be fine

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Non-programming questions are out of the scope of SO. You may want to check [su].

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52531093/8370915). It helps to install JDK step by step.

Answer (score 0):

You $JAVA_HOME already has a suffix "/bin", and you add "/bin" suffix again to $JAVA_HOME in the PATH environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.4`
and set PATH as `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`
JAVA_HOME should point to the "root" of the jdk install, not the bin folder.

Answer (score 0):

i added the /bin after because of one of the fixes had that in. but after i removed i noticed i typed javac - version instead of javac -version which was the other problem, and now that SDK manager detects java i know how to fix the rest. thanks guys