# Having Problems starting Spring Boot Suite

Tags: java, spring-boot

just fyi, i am completely new to everything Java related.
I have to do my own Spring-Boot-Java Application. I watched some Youtube Tutorials and i seem to need Spring Tool Suite to work with a premade Project i made with Spring Initializr.

I installed it but it kept telling me that it was unable to start due to

"A Java Runtime Environment or Java Developement Kit must be available in order to run SprinToolSuite4. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\sts-4.7.0.RELEASE\jre\bin\javaw.exejavaw.exe in your current PATH"

Can someone help? I tried to look for an easy solution and made my own "jre" file within the sts-4.7.0 Release File and copied my Java "bin" file into it, but now it doesnt even give me an error warning and nothing happends when i try to start SpringToolSuite4

Comment: Sounds like maybe you haven't installed Java correctly? Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511778/how-to-install-openjdk-11-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices:

- Add Java to the PATH, e.g. add `C:\prog\Java64\jdk-14\bin;` to the beginning of the PATH.

  In Windows, you do that in the Control Panel.
- Update the `SpringToolSuite4.ini` file with the location of Java.

  Add the following 2 lines **right before** the `-vmargs` line, using a text editor of your choice:

  ```properties
  -vm
  C:/prog/Java64/jdk-14/bin/javaw.exe
  ```

  This takes precedence over the PATH, in case you do both.

In the above, you of course should adjust the path to java as needed for wherever you installed/unzipped Java.