# Flutter Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'. Invalid keystore format

Tags: flutter, build, apk

I'm a bit new to flutter and when I want to generate an apk with "Flutter build apk" I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task 'app: packageRelease'.
com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key test from store "C: \ path \ key.properties": Invalid keystore format
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a conflict between Java versions used by Flutter and Keytool. At least in my case it was.

**1. Check Flutter JDK version**

```
flutter doctor -v
```

It'll be something like `Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8...` 1.8 means Java 8.

**2. Check your computer's JDK version**

```
java -version
```

In my case, it was Java 16, so I had to remove it ([Instruction](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/install/installation-jdk-macos.html#GUID-F9183C70-2E96-40F4-9104-F3814A5A331F)) and install OpenJDK 8.

**3. Install OpenJDK**

MacOS: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openjdk@8

Windows: [Instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52511778/how-to-install-openjdk-11-on-windows)

**4. Update JAVA_HOME**

MacOS:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V  // this will show you jdk versions
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` // specify your version here
```

Windows: [Instruction](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/setting-the-java_home-variable-in-windows-8895.html)

**5. Re-create the keystore**

Remove .jks file and create a new one: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#create-an-upload-keystore